# What are the benefits of using a dependency resolver may be Ninject than using some conditional statement to resolve dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Hello first of all I'm just a newbie programmer, I just discovered how dependency injection pattern works and it is used to make my code more loosely coupled. I don't specifically know how to configure a Ninject to resolve the dependency, is it better to use these plug in?

Currently my approach when resolving dependency is like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    IContract _contract = null;

    MyClass()
    { 
    }

    MyClass(IContract contract)
    {
        _contract = contract;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IContract concreteImplementation = _contract ?? new ConcreteContract();

        concreteImplementation.MyMethod();
    }
}
public class ConcreteContract : IContract
{

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //do something;
    }
}
public interface IContract
{
   void MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: There are some pretty good tuts on both ninject and unity, i'd definitaly recommend that you seek them out. http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2014/01/23/introduction-to-dependency-injection-with-unity.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/988257/Dependency-Injection-using-Unity-container to start with. btw, due to TRUST issues on some shared hosting, I tend to use Unity most of the time nowadays

Comment: Someone's already marked this question for closing as being *too broad*, and it is, indeed, broad. In fact, you can read [an entire book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) on the topic :)

Comment: lol mark - nice book and nice plug :)

Answer (score 1):

Edward...

I thought I'd add a little detail to my comment. The benefits of DI are as you mention (looser coupling). Also, it allows you to register your `contract` at both compile and runtime, depending on your requirement. As a result, you can add new implementations without breaking the class that you wish to resolve against.

You'll need a slight refactor to accomplish your goal using `Unity`. Below is a small self contained example (console app), using your class definitions (and showing an alternative implementation):

```
public class MyClass
{
    readonly IContract _contract = null;

    // do not include a paramterless ctor
    // thus preventing class being created
    // without a concrete implementation of IContract 
    public MyClass(IContract contract)
    {
        _contract = contract;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _contract.MyMethod();
    }
} 

public class ConcreteContract : IContract
{

    public ConcreteContract() { }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //do something;
        Debug.Print("Hello from the ConcreteContract class");
    }
}

public class PlasticContract : IContract
{

    public PlasticContract() { }
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //do something;
        Debug.Print("Hello from the PlasticContract class");
    }
}

public interface IContract
{
    void MyMethod();
}

class Program
{
    // add the nuget package Unity 1st
    // Install-Package Unity
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare a Unity Container -
        // normally done once in the Startup/Bootstrap class
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        // Register IContract so when dependecy is detected
        // it provides a ConcreteContract instance 
        // you could change this to <IContract, PlasticContract>
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IContract, ConcreteContract>();

        // Instance a MyClass class object through Unity
        var preferredClass = unityContainer.Resolve<MyClass>();
        preferredClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Hope this gets you to the next stage.